# jQuery "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JavaScript. I'm trying to run a for loop in order to make the code more readable, but it produces an error:

```
var hiddenInputs = [ '"#input_18_25"', '"#input_18_27_3-1-1"', '"#input_18_27_6-1-1"', '"#input_18_28-1-1"' ];

for( var i = 0; i < hiddenInputs.length; i++ ){
    $(hiddenInputs[i]).addClass('hide');
}
```

I guess it beacue I use double quotation mark that wraps single quotation mark, and it's not recongaize as a string. but if I'm using the following, it's not working:

```
var hiddenInputs = [ '#input_18_25', '#input_18_27_3-1-1', '#input_18_27_6-1-1', '#input_18_28-1-1' ];
```

Bacause it runs as `$(#input_18_25)`.

Comment: jQuery allows you to specify multiple selectors, so you could just do `$('$input_18_25, #input_18_27_3-1-1, ...').addClass('hide')`.

Comment: The second array is the correct way to reference it... are you sure you only have one instance of "input_18_25" on the page?

Comment: Quotation marks are not part of a string's *value*. They only exist for the parser to know where a string value starts and where it ends.  `$('#input_18_25')` is the same as `var foo = '#input_18_25'; $(foo);`. If your second attempt "doesn't work", then something else is wrong.

Comment: You don't need single quotes around the array. Just use double quotes to define string values inside the array. Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/ez8cgsx7/7/

Comment: As @MikeMcCaughan mentioned, jQuery allows multiple selectors. If you already have them in an array like that, instead of a for loop it actually makes more sense to call a `join` on the array.  `$(hiddenInputs.join(",")).addClass('hide')`.  The `join` statement converts the array into a string, with each entry separated by the character passed into `join()`